# kafka-connect Multipart uploads to s3 with s3rver

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to have a full local kafka stack with docker-compose and all my services are up and running (zookeeper, kafka broker, kafka-connect with s3 sink connector etc.)

The producer outputs every second a simple avro object that I want to store in a s3 mock (s3rver). This is how I instantiate the kafka-connect:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-s3-test/config \
    -d '
 {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "test",
        "store.url": "http://s3rver:8000",
        "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "test",
        "flush.size": "1",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
        "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
        "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner"
        }
'
```

But I get the following error:

```
kafka-producer     | [main] INFO ProducerLogger - test-0@947 written to partition 0
kafka-producer     | [main] INFO ProducerLogger - sleep for one second...
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,790] INFO Opening record writer for: topics/test/partition=0/test+0+0000000000.snappy.parquet (io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider)
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,798] INFO Starting commit and rotation for topic partition test-0 with start offset {partition=0=0} (io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter)
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,798] INFO Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 56 (org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter)
s3rver_1           | info: [S3rver] POST /test/topics/test/partition%3D0/test%2B0%2B0000000000.snappy.parquet?uploads 200 253 - 1.167 ms
s3rver_1           | info: [S3rver] Stored object "4d7da2e6e912fd41d4547ef57a056ab3_1" in bucket "test" successfully
s3rver_1           | info: [S3rver] PUT /test/topics/test/partition%3D0/test%2B0%2B0000000000.snappy.parquet?uploadId=4d7da2e6e912fd41d4547ef57a056ab3&partNumber=1 200 - - 2.631 ms
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,813] WARN Aborting multi-part upload with id '4d7da2e6e912fd41d4547ef57a056ab3' (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3OutputStream)
s3rver_1           | info: [S3rver] DELETE /test/topics/test/partition%3D0/test%2B0%2B0000000000.snappy.parquet?uploadId=4d7da2e6e912fd41d4547ef57a056ab3 204 - - 2.809 ms
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,821] ERROR Multipart upload failed to complete for bucket 'test' key 'topics/test/partition=0/test+0+0000000000.snappy.parquet' (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3OutputStream)
kafka-connect      | [2021-02-11 10:53:10,821] ERROR Exception on topic partition test-0:  (io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask)
kafka-connect      | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Multipart upload failed to complete.
kafka-connect      |    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.commitFiles(TopicPartitionWriter.java:506)
kafka-connect      |    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.executeState(TopicPartitionWriter.java:230)
kafka-connect      |    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:188)
kafka-connect      |    at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:190)
```

AS you can see I have my producer emitting an object, it seems it's writing a temporary object to s3 but then kafka-connect fails due to some "multi part" upload stuff. How could I make this work ? I don't really need the multi-part aspect for testing purposes ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to disable multipart requests. Could you use Minio docker container in your tests?

Comment: Does MinIO support those multipart requests?

Comment: I know the connector works with it https://blog.minio.io/journaling-kafka-messages-with-s3-connector-and-minio-83651a51045d?gi=3122e5db0bb

Comment: Thanks! I'll try MinIO then. Please note your link seems broken :)

Comment: Ah. They changed their blog :( Here is an archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20171103050108if_/https://blog.minio.io/journaling-kafka-messages-with-s3-connector-and-minio-83651a51045d